# Athena/Presto Escape Underscore

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I'm trying to escape an underscore in a like operator but not getting any results.  I'm trying to find any rows with a value like 'aa_'.

`WHERE value LIKE '%aa\\_%'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`ESCAPE`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/comparison.html#like):

> Wildcard characters can be escaped using the single character specified for the `ESCAPE` parameter.

```sql
WITH dataset (str) AS (
    VALUES ('aa_1'),
        ('aa_2'),
        ('aa1')
)
SELECT *
FROM dataset 
WHERE str like 'aa\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Output:

| str |
| --- |
| aa_1 |
| aa_2 |